# jsdoc tags within html files

Tags: jsdoc

after building a web app, I tried out the jsdoc-toolkit. In a config file I added my index.html to the list of source files and also used the x-parameter to make the toolkit aware of the html file.

```
java -jar jsrun.jar app\run.js -t=templates\jsdoc -x=html,js -c=conf\my.conf
```

While the doc is generated without any errors, it still ignores any jsdoc annotation I made within the index file. 
And when I check the generated doc, the index.html file is listed as source file.

Very simple documentations such as

```
/**
* testing the doc
* @constructor
*/
function Test(){

}
```

are simply ignored
Probably because its embedded in  tags. 
Do you have any idea how to force jsdoc to use this code as well?

Cheers,
zbug